# Why does vim default markdown ftplugin source html ftplugins? Is there any ways to avoid it?

Tags: html, vim, markdown, ftplugin

all is in the title...
I did a ftplugin to live preview an html file (php and css also) with a browser, but now, when I open a markdown file, the browser opens too... I saw why: there is this line in the default ftplugin/markdown.vim:

```
runtime! ftplugin/html.vim ftplugin/html_*.vim ftplugin/html/*.vim
```

so first question, why does markdown source html ftplugin ? It seems irrevelant for me, but perhaps there are good reasons that I'd be glad to know.

Then, is there a way not to source html ftplugins for markdown files ?

Comment: Only reason I can think of to load html is if you were rendering a preview...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Markdown allows you to use *inline HTML*. [From the spec](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#html):

> For any markup that is not covered by Markdown’s syntax, you simply use HTML itself. There’s no need to preface it or delimit it to indicate that you’re switching from Markdown to HTML; you just use the tags.

That explains the behavior of the filetype plugin.

#### Disabling this

It would be best if you could just disable the mentioned live preview; as this is probably triggered by an `:autocmd BufWritePost <buffer> ...`, you could probably disable it via something like this in your `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/markdown.vim`:

```
:autocmd! BufWritePost <buffer>
```

---

To completely get rid of the HTML stuff, copy the `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/markdown.vim` to your user's `~/.vim/ftplugin/markdown.vim`, and delete / comment out the `:runtime` command. The `b:did_ftplugin` check will ensure that the original ftplugin, though still being sourced, does nothing.

Comment: Ok, I understand now :)
I'll provide a blacklist to disable the plugin on some filtypes. thank you !

Comment: If this is a plugin, users may want to disable the live preview for some HTML buffers, too. The most flexible solution is via a `b:BrowserLivePreviewEnabled` buffer-local variable. You can set this by default, but if it's `0` skip the preview.

Comment: Yes, It's already handled : there are function to activate and toggle the live preview and the preview : see http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4908 for the plugin. But I have to document the browser now^^

Answer (score 1):

You could add this at the top of your `~/.vim/ftplugin/html.vim`:

```
if &ft=="markdown"
  finish
endif
```

this will prevent markdown files from processing the html settings.